# How to assign a new column to a DataFrame without triggering the SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, assign

This question has been asked before in similar examples, however non of the answers I've seen address this particular problem in a satisfactory way (see later).

I have a DataFrame `df` and one of its columns, `df['a']` contains `NaN` values. I remove the `Nan` elements, and then try to create a new column:

```
df = df[~df.isnull()]
df['b'] = False
```

The above gives me a `SettingWithCopyWarning`:

```
/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:517: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self.obj[item] = s
```

However, the error message, and other answers I've seen on stackoverflow, don't seem to have a satisfactory solution. The most common suggestion is `df.loc[:,'b'] = False` but this still seems to give me the warning.

I also tried:

```
df['b'] = np.zeros(len(df), dtype=bool)
df.loc[:,'b'] = np.zeros(len(df), dtype=bool)
```

Yet all still get flagged with Warnings. So what is the correct way to do this, because clearly the warnings imply that I'm doing something wrong? Is there something with the coding practice above that should be avoided? One reason I do the above is in particular to create new columns and lock in their `dtype` (for example above, I don't want the column to be a float).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
df = df.assign(b = False)
```

You can see more details on [pandas.DataFrame.assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)